# Add post ID to AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I am new to AJAX.

I want to add the ID of a post to this simple request.

Anyone? Thanks Martin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Postback to webhook incl PostID</h1>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDocs()">Postback</button>

<p id="testID"></p>

<script>
function loadDocs() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("testID").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "https://hook.integromat.com/h17qasnzptr4lo7cs6br1vmrv28t11ji", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("url=POSTIDHERE");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). What specific problem are you having with the code above? Seems like it should work, provided you replace `POSTIDHERE` with the ID.

Comment: Where is the `postID` located?

Comment: According https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp your code looks fine. goto1 and T.J. Crowder have asked the most important quoestion.

Comment: Thanks for swift responses.
At this moment the postID is only in a custom field.

Comment: @MartinBartels yeah but it's unclear where/what that custom field is, so it's hard to help you.

Comment: Sorry for that! I use this php/hook to populate the Advanced Custom Field named postid 

```
add_filter('acf/load_value', my_load_value, 10, 3);

function my_load_value( $value, $post_id, $field ){

$this_post = get_post();

if( $field[ 'name' ] == 'postid' ){
   $value = $this_post->ID;
}
return $value;

}
```

Comment: @MartinBartels it's still unclear where this value would actually be present in your HTML, would it be inside `<p id="testID">TEST_ID_GOES_HERE</p>`?

Comment: @goto thanks, yes in html like:
<p id="postid">TEST_ID_GOES_HERE</p>
Or other suggestion to make this workout?

Comment: @MartinBartels up to you how to solve this, I don't see anything wrong with this approach. So `document.getElementById("testID").innerHTML = this.responseText;` implies that `this.responseText` is your `TEST_ID`. Is this correct? If so, changing `xhttp.send("url=POSTIDHERE");` to `xhttp.send("url=" + this.responseText)` would do the trick here, or am I missing something?

Comment: @goto: my challenge is:
I want to click button on page XYZ
On button click send a httprequest to webhook (to trigger backend automation proces) no redirect or any other function. 
Only send request to webhook.
So my goal is not to get data from this webhook only trigger my backend automation proces on button click.
For this proces I need the ID of the page on which the button is clicked.
I can hardcopy the postID in query, but I would like this dynamic filled.
The postID is located in advanced custom field.
But I can't get the value in the string.

Comment: @MartinBartels where is the `ID` of the page present in your `HTML`? Is it inside `<p id="testID">HERE</p>`? Not sure what this piece of code is supposed to be doing - `document.getElementById("testID").innerHTML = this.responseText;`. Your "Advanced Custom Field" is a `PHP` code snippet, so unless you have your `ID` somewhere in your `HTML`, this won't be possible to do unless you make a separate call to your `PHP` backend to get the `ID`, then use the response to send  a `POST` request to trigger your webhook.

Comment: Thank you @goto, appreciate your patience in helping me out. In the page HTML I see the ID on several places? data-elementor-type="wp-post" data-elementor-id="228"
So in this case I need to send the data-elementor-id value=228 to the webhook url when clicking on the button, without any redirection. Only postback this value to the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example based on what was mentioned in the comments:

```js
function loadDocs() {
  var element = document.querySelectorAll("[data-elementor-id]")[0];
  var testId = element.dataset.elementorId;

  var URL =
    "https://hook.integromat.com/h17qasnzptr4lo7cs6br1vmrv28t11ji";
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var params = "url=" + testId;

  http.open("POST", URL, true);
  http.setRequestHeader(
    "Content-Type",
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  );
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      console.log("success!");
    }
  };
  http.send(params);
}
```

```html
<h2>Postback to webhook incl PostID</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDocs()">Postback</button>

<!-- This can be any element, but let's assume it's a DIV-->
<div data-elementor-id="228">
  <h2>228</h2>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have an element (`div` in this case) that has the `data-elementor-id` attribute which holds the `testId` you want to `POST` to your Webhook.

I grab this element with `document.querySelectorAll("[data-elementor-id]")[0]` and extract the `ID` by using `element.dataset.elementorId`, which I then use for the `POST` request by using string concatenation - `"url=" + testId`.

Note that `document.querySelectorAll` returns an array - in my case there's only one element on the page with the `data-elementor-id` attribute, so I picked the first one, hence `[0]`. If you had more elements on your page with the same attribute and the first element wasn't the one with appropriate ID, make sure you specify the right index, i.e. `[2]`.

Hope this helps.